# Disallowing Delete from Document prevents movement between folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, onedrive-for-business, delete

I've looked everywhere but it seems that there is an option for Sharepoint365 to disallow document deletion ("Edit" permission group).

I went ahead and removed the delete permission from said group, but now users are not able to move files in between folders. Only solution was to reissue the permission previously removed. Is there a way I can prevent my users from deleting files from the sharepoint drive?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This behavior mirrors NTFS ACLs. A move operation is a Create+Delete operation. If you need the ability for files to be moved, you must grant Delete.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you are not able to this with permissions. The best way to approach this is in my opinion using a remote event receiver attached to the library. It has an event type for deleting and another one for item moving. So, here you can differentiate in custom code what to do in either scenario: prevent the deletion when user tries to delete a document and allow during a move operation.